# core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli-v9

While serving the Angular application, getting below console error in Angular v10

> ```
> core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
>     at _classCallCheck (classCallCheck.js:3)
>     at new Button (button.js:36)
>     at ButtonComponent.<anonymous> (createSuper.js:12)
>     at new ButtonComponent (button.component.ts:30)
>     at NodeInjectorFactory.ButtonComponent_Factory [as factory] (button.component.ts:57)
>     at getNodeInjectable (core.js:4029)
>     at instantiateAllDirectives (core.js:8092)
>     at createDirectivesInstances (core.js:7474)
>     at ɵɵelementStart (core.js:14001)
>     at SBController_Template (template.html:114)
> ```

Demo: https://github.com/kumaresan-subramani/AngularSampleIssue

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. npm i
2. npm run start

**Answer from angular Team** - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18125#issuecomment-672069800

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did have a look on your repo. It looks like your ES `target` has been set as `es5` in your `tsconfig.base.json` file which doesn't support class. I think you have to set it at least from `es6` (`es2015`), then it's supposed to be working:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
  }
}
```

Comment: HI @tmhao2005, `ES target has been set as "es5"in your "tsconfig.base.json" file which doesn't support class` Do you have any doc reference for this?

Comment: Here is the all features get appeared from es2015: http://es6-features.org/#ClassDefinition

Comment: I also don't know why you changed it back to `es5` though?

Comment: It looks like you’re keen to support older browsers which don’t support es6 syntax such as IE, right?

Comment: It looks like this 3rd library (ej2) has something wrong as `babel` transpile code